# Unable to use flow in communities

Tags: community, visual-workflow

I have created a flow that navigates guests users through creating a custom object in a community. I want this flow to be started by clicking a menu item in the tile menu. As of now, it redirects to a page where the flow should appear. Although when i add the component to the page i just get the message "Flows don't run in the canvas so that they don't accidentally do something in your org, like create or delete records.", which is exactly what I'm trying to do. I have looked at the page https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_distribute_external_community.htm&type=5, which says "Flows that were built in the Desktop Flow Designer aren’t supported", but then, what is the point of having a flow component available in communities?

I've also tried having the menu item direct to the flow URL, but then i have trouble navigating the user back to the home screen.

Does anyone have any ideas on what to do? Thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the flow component displays correctly for the guest user when the site i published. This is very unclear. Unless you try it out (by publishing), there is really no way of knowing this.